# What does this syntax mean in python - d = [1, 2, 3][1:]

Tags: python

What is the length of `d`? `d = [1, 2, 3][1:]`. I can't understand what the `[1:]` mean at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s referred to as ‘slicing’. [Examples shown here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/).

From element 1 (the second element) through to the end, therefore a length of 2.

Aside: You’d (hopefully) never see this exact case in real-world practice, as it’s nonsense.

Comment: it means we can assign number of  Values in a lsit and in the same line by using slicing we can restrict to choose and store some specific value. @S3DEV